Call a +page function from +layout
I have a project set up in this way
+layout.svelte
+page.svelte
Component.svelte

The component lives in +layout.svelte, because I need it also in nested routes. The component dispatches a custom event, which is handled by +layout.svelte, but I need to do some actions also in +page.svelte. How can I achieve something like this?
An idea would be to use a store: set the store in some state when the event is dispatched or handled in the +layout.svelte, and listening for changes in +page.svelte. But I wonder if there is a better approach?
I made a MWE here.

Please include all relevant code in the question.

Either way I would use a context if something should span multiple components like this, especially if passed from the layout. (This also prevents the creation of global state which would be shared between all users on the server if there is SSR.)
For passing data reactively through a context, you will need a store (in Svelte 5 state runes can be used), but if reacting to data changes is not enough, you could use an EventTarget or a class inheriting from that instead.
EventTarget objects can serve as an event bus, e.g. some component can use dispatchEvent to send an event and another can use addEventListener to receive them (ideally subscriptions should happen in onMount and be removed again via its returned cleanup function).
